# How do I make turtle face in an organized manner like the "cro" command but in turtle context?

Tags: netlogo

I am trying to make a turret that will fire 8 bullets in 8 directions. In the command I have, they all spawn with heading 0 how do I make them face the right direction. Each turtle should face in a multiple of 45. Just like it would with the cro command in observer context.

```
to fire-tacks
ask ttacks with [alive?] [
set attackSpeed attackSpeed  + .5 
if any? turtles with [is-bloon?] in-radius 5 and attackSpeed >= 12
[set attackSpeed 0
 hatch-btacks 8 [set alive? false set is-turret? false
    set size 1 set damage 1 set color black set is-dart? true set bullet-
speed 4 
]]]
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`range`](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#range) and [`foreach`](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#foreach) to do this (check the links for more detail on how they work). `range` can generate a sequence of the headings you would like, and `foreach` can iterate over that sequence to sprout new turtles with each heading. Have a look at this simplified example:

```
breed [ turrets turret ]
breed [ btacks btack ]

to setup
  ca
  create-turrets 1 [
    setxy random-xcor random-ycor
  ]
  reset-ticks
end

to go
  ask turrets [
    foreach ( range 0 360 45 ) [
      new_heading ->
      hatch-btacks 1 [
        set heading new_heading
        fd 1
      ]
    ]
  ]
end
```